# How to fix error "Failed to resolve:..." on Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, repository

I can't add repository in Gradle.

I was looking for an answer to this question but failed

Build.gradle file in app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mkurbanov.lebap_kwartira"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:x.y.z'
// for experimental rx picker
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:x.y.z'
}
```

Build.gradle file in project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
 all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

such an error is obtained:

> Error:(36, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.esafirm.android-image- 
>   picker:rximagepicker:x.y.z Show in File
> Show in Project Structure 
>   dialog
>
> Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.esafirm.android-image- 
>   picker:imagepicker:x.y.z Show in File
> Show in Project Structure 
>   dialog

I need to add this [repository](https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker).
but it does not work.

Comment: Why are you on Android Studio 1.4?

Comment: I have a weak internet connection.

Comment: replace x.y.x with 1.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Build.gradle replace x.y.z with 1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

change `compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:x.y.z'` to  `compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.1'`

and

`compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:x.y.z'` to

```
compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.13.1'
```